# How move between servlets in java?

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 servlets as shown below. When I run servlet1, and hit submit, I want to pass the parameters to servlet 2 and to display a new webpage generated from servlet2 with the parameters passed. Could anyone advise me what is the best way to achieve this. Thanks.

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { 
        String name = request.getParameter("username"); //assign String variable to "username" parameter
        String address = request.getParameter("useraddress");   //assign String variable to "address" parameter
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     //Creates printwriter object

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();   //create shortcut

        if ((name != null)&&(name.length() >0)&&    //if name is entered
                (String)session.getAttribute(name)!=null){//and if that name has an address associated with it already
            out.println("<h4>The username '"+name+"' is already stored for " 
                +"this session. The address of this user is '"+(String)session.getAttribute(name)+"'.</h4>"); //Print statement
            }//end if


        else if ((name!=null)&&(name.length()>0)&&(address!=null)&&(address.length()>0)){//if name and address fields are not empty
            session.setAttribute(name,address);//save the attritubes as scope variables
            out.println("<h4>The username '"+name+"' and address '"+(String)session.getAttribute(name)+"' has been registered in the system.</h4>");//Print statement
            }//end if 


        else if ((name!=null)&&(name.length()>0)&&((String)session.getAttribute(name)==null)){//if a name is entered and there is no corresponding address stored
            out.println("<h3>User not registered. Please enter a name and address.</h3>");//Print statement
            }//end if

        else if (request.getSession().isNew()==true)    //if it is not a new session
            {       //Print nothing
            }//end if

        else{       //otherwise
            out.println("<h3>Enter valid details to proceed!<h3>"); //Print this message where the other conditions are not met
            }

        out.println("</body></html>"); //close html page
        out.close();//close the PrintWriter
        }//end method
}//end class



@WebServlet("/Servlet2")
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException { 

    response.setContentType("text/html"); //sets content type to html
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     //Creates printwriter object
    // then write the response 
    out.println("<html>" + 
    "<head><title>User Registration Details</title></head>");
    //Get the user details from the html form
    out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">" +
            "<h2>Please enter your name:</h2>" +"<form method=\"get\">" +   
            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"25\">"+  //assign "username" as the variable for the name input field
            "<p></p>"+
            "<h2>Please enter your address:</h2>" +"<form method=\"get\">" +    //Print line
            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"useraddress\" size=\"25\">"+   //assign "useraddress" as the variable for the address input field
            "<p></p>"+
            "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">" +    //Create submit button
            "<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\">" +      //Create reset button
            "</form>");

 }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is read our [`servlets`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) info page. Don't put HTML in Java code. Don't put Java code in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios Delimanolis said in his comment, doing a bunch of out.println's for your HTML inside a servlet is the wrong way to go. Its absolutely hideous and a maintenance nightmare.  So you really do need to read the [servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

But the reason your submit isn't doing anything is that you gave your form no action, so its submitting back to the servlet that prints out the form.  Give it an action attribute with the url of the servlet you expect it to submit to:

```
<form method='get' action='Servlet1'>
```